# Unique wordpress multisite requirement

Tags: multisite

I have wordpress installed on a domain main.domain, but I require a multisite installation. I had previously deployed the multisite on the main domain but I need to remove it since it made the management of the main site an issue.

I want to deploy a multisite at site.main.domain and point every other sub site to subsite.main.domain. I know wordpress could do subsite.site.main.domain or site.main.domain/subsite, but I need to maintain subsite.main.domain.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by editing the site in the network admin, and setting the sites URL to `subsite.main.domain`, WP doesn't force you to have everything as a direct subdomain, you could even put `completelydifferentdomain.com` as the URL and as long as your server is set up to route requests to WP from that domain WP will handle it just fine

Subdomains are just the default, a suggestion. In the old days you might have needed a plugin such as domain mapping, but most of that functionality was put in core along time ago, you would only need it if you needed alias' where a single specific site is served on multiple domains at the same time.